# Get left & right side of optional character inline

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, split

I have the following different types of input `nvarchar` values:

- `FirstName|LastName`
- `FirstName`
- `|LastName`

I need to output `FirstName` and `LastName` as seperate columns in my SQL script.

```
SELECT FLname as Original
    ,SUBSTRING(FLname, 0, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', FLname),0), LEN(FLname)+1)) as FirstName
    ,SUBSTRING(FLname, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', FLname)+1,1), LEN(FLname)+1), LEN(FLname)+1) as LastName
```

**This logic does work**, but I find it unreadable, especially for future developers looking at this.

I know I can create a User Defined Function to store this logic, but I'd rather avoid having to add this.

Is there a neater way of achieving the desired results as an inline SQL statement?

Comment: Well, if you are worried about somebody not understanding what you meant, there are always comments :)

Comment: There is no magic built-in function that will be more readable, e.g. `SplitFirstAndLastNameByPipe()`. If future devs can't comprehend SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX etc. then perhaps they shouldn't be maintaining/modifying this code, or perhaps you should fix the input.

Comment: You can always create the function: SplitFirstAndLastNameByPipe() and put this code in it. Then it's reuseable and it's purpose is clear

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it: (corrected)

```
;WITH cte As
(
    SELECT *,CHARINDEX('|', FLname) As PipeOffset
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT
    FLname As Original,
    CASE When PipeOffset = 0 Then FLname
         When PipeOffset > 1 Then LEFT(FLname, PipeOffset-1)
         ELSE NULL  END     As FirstName,
    CASE When >0 And < LEN(FLname) 
         Then RIGHT(FLname, LEN(FLname)- PipeOffset)
         ELSE NULL  END     As LastName
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much similar to @RBarryYoung's answer using a `CTE` for clear readability with `CHARINDEX`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` function. You can replace empty string (`''`) with null if needed.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b67b/13)

```
;with cte as (
  select FLname, charindex('|',FLname) divider
  from t
)
select FLname original, 
       case when divider = 1 then ''
            when divider > 1 then left(FLname, divider-1) 
       else FLname end firstName,
       case when divider > 0 then right(FLname, len(FLname)-divider)
            else '' end lastName
from cte

|           ORIGINAL | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |
---------------------------------------------
| FirstName|LastName | FirstName | LastName |
|          FirstName | FirstName |          |
|          |LastName |           | LastName |
```